# zend undefined class Zend_View_Helper_Abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am learning Zend Framework. I tried to create a custom view helper class, but the error says "undefined class Zend_View_Helper_Abstract" .

This is Gender.php that is stored at application\views\helpers\
it simply return a string 'he' or 'she' depending on which $gender is passed

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_Gender extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public funtion Gender($gender){
        if ($gender=='m')
        {
            return 'he';
        }else{
            return 'she';
        }
    }
}?>
```

my configs\application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : development]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: This means the Zend_View_Helper_Abstract class is not loaded. Files are not being included, haven't been downloaded, or your Zend install is misconfigured. Unfortunately, this is about as much as we can tell here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the "function" is spelled wrong

```
 public funtion Gender($gender){
```

I don't understand why I got -2 vote. Have people even read the code before down voting? What a busy world

Comment: I guess that votes are due to the response "too easy." (it's debbugage) :) But as we have not found, it is not so easy. :) So +1 for sharing the answer. you should validate it.

Comment: Use good IDE (like Netbeans), so it will show you quickly misspells and common errors.